# C++ Concepts : invalid reference to function concept

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I tried this small piece of code that I modified from the Concepts Technical Specification:

```
  template < typename T >
    concept bool C_Object() {
      return requires {
        T();
      };
    }

  template < typename Object >
  requires C_Object<Object>
  class  Foo {
    public:
      Object  test;
  };

struct Component {
  int data;
  Component() : data(0) {}
};

int main() {
  Foo<Component> test;
  return 0;
}
```

But I get this error :

```
test.cpp:10:12: error: invalid reference to function concept ‘template<class T> concept bool C_Object()’
   requires C_Object<Object>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:26:16: error: template constraint failure
   Foo<Component> test;
                ^
test.cpp:26:16: note:   constraints not satisfied
test.cpp:26:16: note: ill-formed constraint
```

First time I try the new version of C++ concepts, where I am missing?

Thanks

Have a great day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definition:

```
template < typename T >
concept bool C_Object() {
  return requires {
    T();
  };
}
```

defines `C_Object` as a function concept. This one:

```
template < typename Object >
requires C_Object<Object>
class Foo {
public:
  Object test;
};
```

uses `C_Object` as if it were a variable concept. In a requires clause, you must use `()` to "invoke" function concepts:

```
template < typename Object >
requires C_Object<Object>()
class Foo {
public:
  Object test;
};
```

Alternatively, you could use the "terse" placeholder syntax to constrain `Object` which does not differentiate variable and function concepts:

```
template < C_Object Object >
class Foo {
public:
  Object test;
};
```

Comment: Your last code was something I was searching, big thanks :)